# How to custom message on browser when internet is not connected

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to show custom message when my web application is failed to connect to internet.

Currently when my internet connectivity fails then the browser shows `"unable to connect" or "server not found"`. so I want to show my custom message on my page.

I have written this :

```
bool bb = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
if (bb == true)
{
  //custom message
}
else
   //meesage
```

But still it is not working.

How can I show that?

Comment: Aehem. The server not found, unable to connect  means that the browser did not manage to connect to the server. So how should the server be able then to send a message to the browser?

Comment: Check this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Comment: yes. but is there any way to show that message from cache ?

Comment: So in essence you want to put the message into cache and let it show in case there is no connection to our page? if so pls mark that appropriately in your question as that changes things considerably in what you mean with the question (also mark it in the topic name). Aside from that I don't think its possible but will let myself be surprised if I'm mistaken or not.

Comment: can we do that with the java script ?

Comment: @deepak may be with js you should sent a periodical async query to server, wait for some seconds and if you don't get any response - show error message. Is it what are you looking for?

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are expecting internet connectivity from browser, if so use navigator.onLine;

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var isOnline = navigator.onLine;
    if (!isOnline)
        alert("Your custom message for no internet connectivity!!!");
</script>
```

Comment: No. when i disconnect internet then still it shows the unable to connect message instead this custom alert message.

Comment: Your browser may not support, it works in IE and Chrome - I've tested in these browsers.

Comment: i am checking on mobile chrome browser and it is also not working in firefox.

Comment: Nope - I've verified in desktop browsers

Comment: can you give me any live demo /link  of it.?

Comment: Please check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Answer (score 0):

Periodically call from client to server, and if there is no answer or not expecting answer - show error message.

for **web forms**:
create handler with implemetation of `ProcessRequest` like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Ok");
    }
```

for **mvc**:
create action with simple result like this:

```
public ActionResult CheckInternetConnection()
{
    return Json("Ok");
}
```

of course, this request handlers should not require any authorization or another pretreatment

then create js `timer` and method for request

```
var maxTime = <your interval time>;
var timer;

//write own method for check request
function performRequest() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // reserve 1 sec for timeout function execution
    // if we didn't - you can get a situation when 
    // simultaneously performing more than 1 request
    xhr.timeout = maxTime - 1000; 
    xhr.ontimeout = function {
        //waiting to long
        alert('<your message>');
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    };

    xhr.open('GET', '<url of your check connection handler>', true);

    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4)
            return;

        if (xhr.responseText !== 'OK') {
            //Can't access to handler
            alert('<your message>');
            window.clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
}

//after page load start request timer
document.onload += function () {
    timer = window.setInterval(performRequest, maxTime);
}
```

I haven't debug this code.